# How to create a dropdown list tab in docusign using power automate

Tags: automation, docusignapi, power-automate

I have a power automate flow that creates a docusign envelope with a Microsoft Word document. (this is similar to the steps descibed [in this docusign blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/expanding-power-automate-series-send-envelope)).
The flow replaces a number of anchor strings in the word document with docusign tags, using the powerautomate task of type “Add tabs for a recipient on an envelope”. I am can do this when I select and use the predefined Tab Types listed on the task, such as text. I would like to create a dropdown list tab in my document but this type of tag is not predefined. So I have entered a custom value to define the array for the dropdown list as shown in this image.

[Image of taskDetails/Tab and flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Azzd.png)

When I test the flow, I get the following error :
Output body:

```
"body": {
        "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
        "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. No tabs specified."
    }
}
```

The input for the task is:

```
{
  "accountId": "448859da---------",
  "envelopeId": "f165e375--------",
  "recipientId": "50887345",
  "tabType": "List",
  "tabDetails/tabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "ListTab",
      "anchorString": "/Department/",
      "Items": [
        {
          "text": "HR",
          "value": "HR"
        },
        {
          "text": "ICT",
          "value": "ICT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Logistics",
          "value": "Logistics"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I properly define my custom value?
Alternatively, if this is not possible using this particular powerautomate task, how can I do this using any other task such as HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JSON you need, if it's not supported by the PowerAutomate Connector, you may need to write your own connector:

```
  {
  "listTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "Dropdown123",
      "conditionalParentLabel": null,
      "conditionalParentValue": null,
      "isPrefilledTab": false,
      "fontSize": "size9",
      "underline": false,
      "italic": false,
      "fontColor": "black",
      "bold": false,
      "font": "lucidaconsole",
      "required": true,
      "locked": false,
      "shared": false,
      "width": 0,
      "shareToRecipients": "",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "documentId": "2",
      "xPosition": 280,
      "yPosition": 172,
      "height": 0,
      "listItems": [
        {
          "selected": true,
          "text": "test1",
          "value": "test1"
        },
        {
          "selected": false,
          "text": "test2",
          "value": "234"
        }
      ],
      "trackingId": "c297",
      "trackingid": "c297"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here are Approve/Decline Tabs:**

```
{
  "approveTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "Approve1",
      "conditionalParentLabel": null,
      "conditionalParentValue": null,
      "isPrefilledTab": false,
      "fontSize": "size9",
      "underline": false,
      "italic": false,
      "fontColor": "black",
      "bold": false,
      "font": "helvetica",
      "name": "",
      "height": 22,
      "width": 70,
      "recipientId": "1",
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "documentId": "2",
      "buttonText": "Approve",
      "xPosition": 177,
      "yPosition": 170,
      "trackingId": "c297",
      "trackingid": "c297"
    }
  ],
  "declineTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "Decline1",
      "conditionalParentLabel": null,
      "conditionalParentValue": null,
      "isPrefilledTab": false,
      "fontSize": "size9",
      "underline": false,
      "italic": false,
      "fontColor": "black",
      "bold": false,
      "font": "helvetica",
      "name": "",
      "height": 22,
      "width": 70,
      "recipientId": "1",
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "documentId": "2",
      "buttonText": "Decline",
      "xPosition": 256,
      "yPosition": 169,
      "trackingId": "c312",
      "trackingid": "c312"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Inbar, this worked well. I also realized that for the powerautomate task “Add tabs for a recipient on an envelope” to understand the JSON I needed to specify that the tag type is a custom type of "ListItems" and not "List" as I had used. Please could you also share the JSON for Approval, Decline and Initialize, which i also need to use?

Comment: Added some JSON for Approve/Decline. Not sure what is Initialize, haven't heard of that one yet.

Comment: Thanks @Inbar. 
According to [this blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-tab-types), initial here is similar to signature but the signer only puts the initials of their name.

Comment: Yes, that is correct